# How to delete the listbox item in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Listbox having 2 buttons.When click on button need to delete the item from that listbox.
please tell me how to acheive that?

```
 List<SampleCheckedData> interestrates = new List<SampleCheckedData>();
  interestrates = (from rts in xmlDocu.Descendants("Friend")

                                 select new SampleCheckedData
                                 {

                                     Id = (string)rts.Element("userid"),
                                     Name = (string)rts.Element("name"),
                                     Icon = (string)rts.Element("imageurl"),
                                     VisibleStatus = (string)rts.Element("visiblestatus"),
                                     AppStatus = (string)rts.Element("loginstatus"),

                                     imgBubble =bitmapRed,
                                 }).ToList<SampleCheckedData>();



                this.lstImages.ItemsSource = interestrates;

 private void btnAccept_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int _id = int.Parse(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).Tag.ToString());
            lstFriendRequuest.Items.RemoveAt(lstFriendRequuest.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the selected item,

```
listbox.Items.RemoveAt(listbox.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Hi getting operation is not only supproted on read only collection.

Comment: @WP7 if it's a read only collection, you'll need to build a new collection that doesn't contain the items that you don't want, and bind to that...

Answer (score 0):

Make your collection available globally on this page, and now you can manipulate on it easily from `btnAccept_MouseEnter` event:

```
public interestrates;

...
{
    interestrates = ...
    this.lstImages.ItemsSource = interestrates;
}

private void btnAccept_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    interestrates.RemoveAt(lstFriendRequuest.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Also, make sure that a click on a `ListBox` item changes `SelectedIndex` accordingly